# Regex not matching 6 repeated numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, expression, repeat

I am trying to get a regular expression to work but am stumped. What I want is to do the inverse of this:

```
/(\w)\1{5,}/
```

This regex does the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do.  I would like to get everything but a string that has 6 repeating numbers i.e. `111111` or `999999`.

Is there a way to use a negative look-around or something with this regex?

Comment: Is a string with 7 repeating numbers OK? Also your regex doesn't make sense. Why is 1 escaped? Are you just that isn't a regex used in a substitution regex?

Comment: What is the computing language or tool you are using?

Comment: To be clear, I am using a jQuery plugin called validation engine.  I am trying to add a custom regex to the language file.  I am just starting to dig into regex and am very novice.  The regex I pasted above was something I found online that seems to work on regexr.com to find repeating numbers.  And yeah, the user can only input 6 numbers so 7 repeating numbers is ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this rgex:

```
/^(?!.*?(\w)\1{5}).*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF5qI5/4)

`(?!.*?(\w)\1{5})` is a negative lookaahead that will fail the match if there are 6 consecutive same word characters in it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather go with the `\d` [shorthand class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for digits since `\w` also allows letters and an underscore.

```
^(?!.*(\d)\1{5}).*$
```

**Regex explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string/line anchor
- `(?!.*(\d)\1{5})` - The negative lookahead checking if after an optional number of characters (`.*`) we have a digit (`(\d)`) that is immediately followed with 5 identical digits (`\1{5}`).
- `.*` - Match 0 or more characters up to the
- `$` - End of string/line.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM7kX1/3). This regex will allow

Comment: Thank you!  This worked and the explanation was great for a rookie like myself :)

Comment: Nice ! Solve my problem: same digit repeated nine times => ^(\d)\1{8}$. Thank you (+1)